# Creating a plot in Netlogo from a .csv file

Tags: csv, netlogo

I want to create two plots in NetLogo from CSV files.

I have two csv files with one row of data each. I have 730 data points each row which I want to plot in the the model as a baseline for comparison with the model results.

I get the error: Plot inspected to be an input but got a list instead.

Thanks in advance.

```
    extensions[
csv]

globals [

 real_thc         
 real_tnhc        
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor 39]
  reset-ticks

end

to go
plot_go1
plot_go2
tick
end

to plot_go1
  file-open "thc.csv"
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set real_thc csv:from-row file-read-line
  
  file-close
end

to plot_go2
  file-open "tnhc.csv"
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set real_tnhc csv:from-row file-read-line
  file-close
end
```

Comment: Can you share your plotting code, or- preferably- make a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create your plot one point at a time, not all at once. Using `foreach` combined with brackets, you can go through two lists at the same time  and plot the corresponding point.

`(foreach list1 list2 [ [x y] -> plotxy x y])`

It will combine the first item of both lists for the first point, the second item of both lists for the second point etc. Note also how I use `plotxy` instead of `plot`, since `plot` only allows you to input the y-value and assumes the x-values to be incremented by a fixed interval for each next call.

Putting all that into a minimal reproducible example gives us the following code:

```
globals [list1 list2]

to setup
  
  ca
  set list1 [1 2 1.5 4 7] ;x-values
  set list2 [7 8 3 5 6] ;y-values
  
end


to go
  set-current-plot "plot 1"
  
  (foreach list1 list2 [ [x y] -> plotxy x y])

end
```